# ValueProviderSupport from package org.springframework.shell.standard.ValueProviderSupport not supported in spring-shell-starter :3.1.3

Tags: spring-shell

Currently our project has spring-shell-starter with version 2.0.1.RELEASE we have tried upgrading to spring-shell-starter :3.1.3

but facing an issue with "Cannot resolve symbol '`ValueProviderSupport` "  from

```
package org.springframework.shell.standard.ValueProviderSupport
```

Could you please provide any migration guide available from 2.X to 3.X